# How do I manage the state of each index in an iterated over array REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am super new to React but pretty familiar with javascript in general. Been having a really tough time getting started with React and was wondering if someone could explain to me how I should manage the state on the following three buttons.

MY MAIN COMPONENT:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var classNames = require('classnames');
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Fans from './Buttons'

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Buttons:[
        { src: '/src/images/1.svg',
          button: 1
        },
        { src: '/src/images/2.svg',
          button: 2
        },
        {
          src: '/src/images/3.svg',
          button: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    var buttons = this.state.Buttons.map(function(button){
      return(<Buttons key={button.button} 
              buttNum={button.button} 
              src={button.src} 
               />);
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {buttons}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

MY BUTTON COMPONENT:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import classnames from 'classnames';
var classNames = require('classnames');

export default class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isActive: false}
    this.selectButton = this.selectButton.bind(this)
  }

  selectButton() {
    let active = !this.state.isActive;
    this.setState({isActive: active})
  }

  render() {
    let classes = classnames('btn-success', {selected: this.state.isActive});
    return (
      <img src={this.props.src} 
      buttNum={this.props.key} 
      onClick={this.selectButton}
      className={classes} />
    );
  }
};
```

HOW DO I MANAGE STATE ON THE INDIVIDUAL BUTTONS?! Why is this so difficult to achieve... with jQuery or Angular this can be done with 5 lines of code!

I am simply trying to make the 'selected' class only be available to one button at a time - instead selected can be toggled on individual buttons but I have no idea how to manage the state of all the buttons with my current selectButton() click handler. Currently I only have access to the state of the button that was clicked...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to handle all states from the parent (main) component. Each Button item in the main state should contain `isActive` and should only be changed in the main component. Child components should be "dumb" and not know the state or be able to change state. If you pass the child component a function to call `onChange` as a prop, it can trigger that function in the main component and change the state there. Below find a starting point in order to do what you're looking for.

Main component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var classNames = require('classnames');
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Fans from './Buttons'

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Buttons:[
        { src: '/src/images/1.svg',
          button: 1,
          isActive: false
        },
        { src: '/src/images/2.svg',
          button: 2,
          isActive: false
        },
        {
          src: '/src/images/3.svg',
          button: 3,
          isActive: fasle
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  changeActive(index) {
    var buttonArray = this.state.Buttons;
    for (var i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
      let active = !buttonArray[i].isActive;
      if (index - 1 === index) {
        buttonArray[i].isActive = active;
      } else {
        buttonArray[i].isActive = false;
      }
    }
    this.setState({Buttons : buttonArray});
  }

  render() {
    var buttons = this.state.Buttons.map(function(button){
      return(<Buttons key={button.button} 
              buttNum={button.button} 
              src={button.src},
              changeActive={this.changeActive}
               />);
    })

    return (
      <div>
        {buttons}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Button component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import classnames from 'classnames';
var classNames = require('classnames');

export default class Buttons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isActive: false}
    this.selectButton = this.selectButton.bind(this)
  }

  selectButton() {
    this.props.changeActive(this.props.buttNum);
  }

  render() {
    let classes = classnames('btn-success', {selected: this.state.isActive});
    return (
      <img src={this.props.src} 
      buttNum={this.props.key} 
      onClick={this.selectButton}
      className={classes} />
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks @erichrardson30 this makes much more sense than what I was trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately the changeActive(index) function you wrote does not work and I have no idea how to fix it. How does one call this.setState on a specific index of the array without throwing a syntax error?

Comment: @MaxwellLasky I updated that function. Sorry about that. You can't just update State on an item in an array. You have to make a copy of it, update the copy to what you want and then set the State of the entire array.

Comment: Wow ok thanks - crazy to me that in the React component API Docs this is not mentioned as the first thing in this.setState()... thanks again

Comment: @MaxwellLasky no problem!